# How can I export the database from AWS QLDB, for migration purpose to any Ethereum platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

There is an **Export journal** option available but I don't think it contains all the tables.
I want to retrieve the current state of the database.
Can anyone please help me on this ?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what your expectation would be as per the "current state of the database" ? Are you expecting that only the latest revision can get exported ?

Comment: Not only the latest revision but I want a way in which I can extract the up to date database with all the revisions till date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export contains everything. Every transaction, every table, every revision.

Comment: +1, to add, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/export-journal.output.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/journal-contents.html contain more references to journal content.